# Why would a PHP if() Statement cause a 500 error?

Tags: php

I'm setting up a simple script to send SMS through Twillio, and record the messages in the database. All the code runs fine until I add an IF statement.

A form is used to enter the phone number and message, which is sent (POST) to the process.php file, which send the message through the Twillio API and logs it in the database.

I'm pretty good with PHP, it's a very basic IF statement I have used thousands of times before, but this 500 error has me stumped.

```
if(isset($_POST['phone_number'])) {

    $sms_to = $_POST['phone_number'];
    $sms_body = $_POST['sms_message'];

    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

... Lots more code

} else {
    echo "Sorry, message not sent. No phone number was entered.";
}
```

I have triple checked all the code to make sure there was no errors, which it does run fine, until I add the if statement.

Comment: What is the actual error? A `500 error` is a general server error, the logs should have details about what is causing error.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. If adding this if/else causes an error, then you've probably wrapped the open/close parens at different levels, and you're now unbalanced.

Comment: Try to print error. And paste the error so we can give best possible solution.

Comment: @AlexHowansky , That was my first thought, but they are in the correct places.  I checked them manually and both Sublime and Dreamweaver is showing them as correct too.

Comment: @MonishKhatri no errors showing other than HTTP 500 ERROR - currently unable to handle this request.

Comment: You need to check the server log file, not the browser screen.

Comment: @AlexHowansky The server log is not showing anything at all, either is the error_log file in the root directory. This is why I am so stumped on this one.

Comment: Found the culprit..   Twilio REST API won't work within an IF statement....
        use Twilio\Rest\Client;

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL)` put this in your script and you'll get exact error. Than post the error here or solve it.

Comment: @MonishKhatri No errors showing for anything, but I did find it with a bit more manual debugging.. it was "use Twilio\Rest\Client;", part of the Twillio REST API.

Comment: Who closed this question? The duplicate post does not answer the question. As I said multiple time, no errors are showing.

Comment: _"Twilio REST API won't work within an IF statement"_ This makes no sense. Whether or not you're inside an if statement has nothing to do with the error due to lack of a `use` statement. Your problem isn't the if statement, it's the erroneous code you added inside it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky The code inside it works fine, until the if statement is added.

Comment: @AlexHowansky.. This works... `if(isset($sms_body)) {

    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
}
    use Twilio\Rest\Client;`
...  This doesn't...  `if(isset($sms_body)) {

    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

    use Twilio\Rest\Client;
}`

Comment: Your autoloader config shouldn't be inside a conditional, just move the require to the top of the file and always run it.